# Not display this in different page

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a 2 page

Myorderhistoyr.phtml

invoice.phtml

in below code is working in **invoice.phtml** but same code i used in **Myorderhistoyr.phtml** but it's not display anything

```
  <?php 
$isPartner= Mage::getModel('marketplace/userprofile')->isPartner(); 
$helper= Mage::helper('marketplace');
if($isPartner==1){
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined'){
        document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
    }
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

    <?php //$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    //$customer_name =  $customer->getName(); // Full Name  ?>
    <!-- <div class="page-title">
        <h1 style="float:left;"><?php //echo "$customer_name" ." Order History"; ?></h1>
    </div> -->
    <div class="wk_mp_design">
        <!-- <div class="block block-account">  
            <div class="block-title">   
                <strong><span><h4><?php //echo $helper->__('Order History') ?></h4></span></strong>
            </div>
        </div> -->

        <div class="fieldset wk_mp_fieldset">
            <div class="grid">
                <div class="hor-scroll">
                    <form action="<?php echo Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();?>" method="post">
                        <table cellspacing="0" class="border wk_mp_list_table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr id="wk_mp_tr_heading">
                                    <th><span><?php echo $helper->__('Order Id') ?></span></th>
                                    <th><span><?php echo $helper->__('Date') ?></span></th>
                                    <th><span><?php echo $helper->__('Order Status') ?></span></th>
                                    <th><span>&nbsp;</span></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody class="wk_mp_body">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" class="input-text" name="s" placeholder='<?php echo $helper->__('Search by Order Id') ?>' value="<?php echo $this->getRequest()->getParam('s')?>"/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span class="wk_mp_td_span">
                                            <?php //echo $helper->__('From: ') ?>
                                            <input name="from_date" id="special_from_date" class="input-text" value="<?php echo $this->getRequest()->getParam('from_date')?>" placeholder='<?php echo $helper->__('From:') ?>' />
                                        </span>                             
                                        <span class="wk_mp_td_span">
                                            <?php //echo $helper->__('To: ') ?>
                                            <input name="to_date" id="special_to_date" class="input-text" value="<?php echo $this->getRequest()->getParam('to_date')?>" placeholder='<?php echo $helper->__('To:') ?>' />
                                        </span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="orderstatus" class="input-text">
                                            <option value=""><?php echo $helper->__('All') ?></option>
                                            <?php 
                                            $orderstatus_coll = Mage::getModel('sales/order_status')->getResourceCollection()->getData();
                                            foreach ($orderstatus_coll as $orderstatus) {
                                                ?>
                                                <option value="<?php echo $orderstatus['status']?>" <?php if($this->getRequest()->getParam('orderstatus') == $orderstatus['status']) echo 'selected="selected"'?>>
                                                    <?php echo $orderstatus['label'] ?>
                                                </option>
                                                <?php
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button class="button" title="Save" id="save_butn" type="submit">
                                            <span><span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Submit') ?></span></span></span>
                                        </button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                    <?php 
                    if(count($this->getCollection())==0){ ?>        
                        <div class="fieldset wk_mp_fieldset">
                            <div class="wk_emptymsg">
                                <?php echo $helper->__('No Order Available') ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php 
                    } else{ ?>
                        <?php $i=0;
                        foreach($this->getCollection() as $res){
                            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($res['mageorderid']);
                            $status=$order->getStatus();
                            $name=$order->getCustomerName();
                            if($res['mageorderid']>0){
                                $i++;?>
                                <div class="wk_orderbox <?php if($i==1) echo "wk_first_order"?>">
                                    <div class="order_summery">
                                        <div class="wk_orderbox_content1">
                                            <!-- <div class="wk_orderbox_details">
                                                <div class="color">
                                                    <span class="wk_ordertitle_label"><?php //echo $helper->__('Order') ?></span> <strong>#<?php //echo $res['magerealorderid']; ?></strong>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="name">
                                                    <?php //echo Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getpronamebyorder($res['mageorderid']); ?>                                        

                                                </div>
                                            </div>-->
                                            <div class="wk_orderbox_details">
                                            <input type="button" value=" <?php echo $helper->__('Order') ?>#<?php echo $res['magerealorderid']; ?>" id="hideshow<?php echo $res['magerealorderid']; ?>" class="buttontoggle">
                                                <div id="content<?php echo $res['magerealorderid']; ?>" style="display: none;">
                                                     <?php echo Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getpronamebyorder($res['mageorderid']); ?> 
                                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                                    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                                                      $('#hideshow<?php echo $res['magerealorderid']; ?>').live('click', function(event) { 

                                                             $('#hideshow<?php echo $res['magerealorderid']; ?>').toggleClass( "ordershow" );       
                                                             $('#content<?php echo $res['magerealorderid']; ?>').toggle('3000');

                                                        });

                                                     });

                                                    </script>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="check_now">

                                            <?php 
                                            $_order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($this->getRequest()->getParam('id')); 
                                            $helper=Mage::helper('marketplace');
                                            $orderItems=$this->getOrderItems();
                                            foreach($orderItems as $item) {
                                                $mageorderid = $item->getMageorderid();
                                                $item_status="";
                                                foreach($_order->getAllItems() as $itemdata) {
                                                    if($itemdata->getProductId()==$item->getMageproid())
                                                        $item_status=$itemdata->getStatus();
                                                }
                                            }
                                            ?>

                                            <?php 
                                                    $tracking = $this->getTrackingNumber($_order->getId()); 
                                                    if($tracking!=""){
                                                        $shipmentId = $tracking->getShipmentId();
                                                        $invoiceId=$tracking->getInvoiceId();
                                                    }
                                                ?>






        <!-- Custom Order Status display -->
                                <?php $custom_order_status = $_order->getStatusLabel(); ?>
                                <?php //echo $custom_order_status;?>
        <!-- Custom Order Status display -->

        <?php if ($custom_order_status != 'Completed' && $custom_order_status !='Canceled'){?>
        <div class="wk_mp_order-info-box">
            <div class="box box-payment">

                <?php if ($custom_order_status == 'RTO'){?>

                    <div class="rto_status">
                        <strong><?php echo "This Order Has been  RTO State You can't able to Process"; ?>
                        </strong>
                    </div>

                <?php }
                    else{ ?>
                <div class="box-title">
                    <h2>
                        <span><?php echo $this->__('Process Your Order ') ?></span>
                    </h2>
                </div>
                <?php }?>
                <div class="box-content">
                <?php
                    $orderItems=$this->getOrderItems();
                    foreach($orderItems as $item) {
                        $item_status="";
                        foreach($_order->getAllItems() as $itemdata) {
                            if($itemdata->getProductId()==$item->getMageproid())
                                $item_status=$itemdata->getStatus();
                        }
                    }
                    $shipping_coll = Mage::getModel('mpshippingmanager/tracking')->getCollection()
                                    ->addFieldToFilter('order_id',array('eq'=>$this->getRequest()->getParam('id')))
                                    ->addFieldToFilter('seller_id',array('eq'=>Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId()));
                    if(count($shipping_coll)){?>
                        <?php 
                        $tracking=$this->getTrackingNumber($_order->getId());
                        if($tracking!=""){
                            $disabled=$tracking->getTrackingNumber()==''? "":"readonly='readonly'";
                            $shipmentId = $tracking->getShipmentId();
                            $invoiceId=$tracking->getInvoiceId();
                            $shippingamount=$tracking->getShippingCharges();
                        }
                        if($_order->getStatus()=='pending' && $vendor_item_status!='canceled'){?>
                            <div class="scontent_status">
                                <span><?php echo $helper->__('Please Wait for Order Approve Your Admin');?></span></div>
                        <?php
                        }elseif(strtolower($vendor_item_status)=='canceled'){?>
                            <h3 class="scontent_status"><?php echo $helper->__('Order Canceled');?></h3>
                        <?php
                        }else{
                        ?>
                            <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpshippingmanager/shipping/savetrackingnumber')?>" id="shipping-form" method="post">



                                <div class="shipping_top" style="display:none">
                                    <span class="shipping_service"><?php echo $helper->__('Carrier');?></span>
                                    <span class="row_total"><?php echo $helper->__('Tracking Number');?></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="items">
                                    <input class="required-entry" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_order->getId(); ?>" name="order_id"/>
                                    <div class="wk_item">
                                        <span class="carrier" style="display:none"><input class="required-entry carrier" value="<?php echo $tracking->getCarrierName(); ?>" <?php echo $disabled;?> type="text" name="carrier"/></span>
                                        <span class="row_total wk_track_input" style="display:none">
                                            <!-- <input value="<?php //echo $tracking->getTrackingNumber(); ?>" <?php //echo $disabled;?> type="text" name="tracking_id"/> -->
                                            <input value="0" type="text" name="tracking_id"/>
                                        </span>
                                        <div class="order-status">
                                        <?php if(count($shipping_coll)): ?>
                                            <?php if($item_status=="Ordered"): ?>
                                                <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpshippingmanager/shipping/cancelorder',array('id'=>$mageorderid))?>">
                                                    <button class="button wk_mp_btn" style="flaot:none" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Cancel Order') ?>" type="button" id="save_butn" >
                                                        <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel Order') ?></span></span>
                                                    </button>
                                                </a>
                                            <?php endif;  ?>
                                        <?php endif; ?>

                                        <?php if($item_status=="Ordered"||$item_status=="Invoiced"){?>

                                            <button class="button wk_mp_btn" style="flaot:none" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Generate Invoice') ?>" type="submit" id="save_butn" >
                                                <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Invoice') ?></span></span>
                                            </button>
                                        <?php } ?>


                                        <!-- Custom Order Status -->
                                        <?php if ($custom_order_status == 'Invoiced'){?>
                                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpshippingmanager/shipping/shipementorder',array('id'=>$mageorderid))?>">
                                          <button class="button wk_mp_btn" style="flaot:none" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Shipment') ?>" type="button" id="save_butn" >
                                          <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Shipment') ?></span></span>
                                          </button>
                                        </a> 
                                        <?php }?>


                                        <?php if ($custom_order_status == 'Shipement'){?>
                                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpshippingmanager/shipping/rtoorder',array('id'=>$mageorderid))?>">
                                          <button class="button wk_mp_btn" style="flaot:none" title="<?php echo $helper->__('RTO') ?>" type="button" id="save_butn" >
                                          <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('RTO') ?></span></span>
                                          </button>
                                        </a>
                                        <?php }?>

                                        <!-- Custom Order Status -->





                                    </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>


                        <?php 
                        } ?>
                    <?php
                    }else{
                        echo $_order->getShipping_description();
                    }?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php }?>

                                        </div>
                                            <?php //echo $status;?>

                                            <div class="order_details">

                                                    <?php
                                                        $shipping_coll = Mage::getModel('mpshippingmanager/tracking')->getCollection()
                                                                        ->addFieldToFilter('order_id',array('eq'=>$res['mageorderid']))
                                                                        ->addFieldToFilter('seller_id',array('eq'=>$res['mageproownerid']));
                                                        if(count($shipping_coll)): ?>
                                                        <?php if ($status !='pending' && $status != 'canceled'){?>
                                                            <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpshippingmanager/shipping/invoice',array('id'=>$res['mageorderid']))?>" >
                                                                <button class="button" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Process Your Order') ?>" type="button">
                                                                    <span><span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Invoice') ?></span></span></span>
                                                                </button>
                                                            </a>
                                                            <?php }?>
                                                        <?php endif;?>

                                                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/vieworder',array('id'=>$res['mageorderid']))?>">
                                                        <button class="button" title="<?php echo $helper->__('View Order') ?>" type="button">
                                                            <span><span><span><?php echo $helper->__('View') ?></span></span></span>
                                                        </button>
                                                    </a>
                                                </div>


                                            <div class="wk_dash_orderstatus">

                                                <div class="ma"><?php //echo $sta = "Status";?></div>

                                                <label for="name" class="wk_dash_label">
                                                        <div class="status <?php echo strtolower($status); ?>"><?php echo strtoupper($status); ?> 
                                                        </div>
                                                </label> 

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="pending_ststus">
                                            <?php if ($status =='pending'){

                                            echo "Please Wait for Admin Approval";

                                            }?>
                                        </div>

                                            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="wk_orderbox_content2">
                                            <div class="wk_orderbox_details">
                                                <div class="wk_orderbox_details_customer">
                                                    <span class="wk_title_label"><?php echo $helper->__('Customer: ');?></span>
                                                    <span class="wk_label"><?php echo $name;?></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="wk_orderbox_details_date">
                                                <span class="wk_title_label"><?php echo $helper->__('Date: ');?></span>
                                                <span class="wk_label"><?php echo $res['cleared_at'];?></span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="wk_orderbox_total">
                                                <span class="wk_title_label"><?php echo $helper->__('Order Total: ');?></span>
                                                <span class="wk_label"><strong><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency(Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getPricebyorder($res['mageorderid']));?></strong>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="wk_clear"></div>
                            <?php }
                        }   ?>
                        <?php
                    }?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php echo $this->getPagerHtml(); ?>        
        </div>  

    </div>
    <script> 
        var $wk_jq=jQuery.noConflict();
        (function($wk_jq){
            $wk_jq( "#special_from_date" ).datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"});
            $wk_jq( "#special_to_date" ).datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"});          
        })($wk_jq);
    </script>
<?php 
}else{
    echo "<h2 class='wk_new_msg'>".$helper->__("To BECOME SELLER PLEASE CONTACT TO ADMIN.")."</h2>";
}?>
```

**xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>   
<layout version="0.1.0">   
    <customer_account>
        <block name="marketplacenavigation">
            <block type="core/template" name="shippingleftlink" template="mpshippingmanager/shippingleftlink.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </customer_account>

    <mpshippingmanager_shipping_index>
        <update handle="customer_account"/>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>marketplace/mpshippingmanager/css/mpshipping.css</stylesheet></action>
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>marketplace/css/style.css</stylesheet></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
             <block type="core/template" name="mpshippingmanager" as="mpshippingmanager" template="mpshippingmanager/index.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </mpshippingmanager_shipping_index>

    <marketplace_account_salesdetail>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>marketplace/mpshippingmanager/css/mpshipping.css</stylesheet></action>
        </reference>
         <update handle="customer_account"/>
          <reference name="content">
            <block type="mpshippingmanager/salesdetail" name="marketplace_salesdetail" as="marketplace_salesdetail" template="mpshippingmanager/salesdetail.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </marketplace_account_salesdetail>

    <marketplace_account_invoice>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>marketplace/mpshippingmanager/css/mpshipping.css</stylesheet></action>
        </reference>
        <update handle="customer_account"/>
          <reference name="content">
            <block type="mpshippingmanager/invoice" name="marketplace_invoice" template="mpshippingmanager/invoice.phtml"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </marketplace_account_invoice>

    <marketplace_account_orderhistory>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>marketplace/mpshippingmanager/css/mpshipping.css</stylesheet></action>
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>marketplace/mpshippingmanager/css/datepicker/jquery-ui.css</stylesheet></action>    
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <remove name="marketplace_myorderhistory"></remove>
            <block type="mpshippingmanager/invoice" name="mpshipping_invoice" template="mpshippingmanager/ordershipslip.phtml" before="_"/>
            <block type="marketplace/products" name="marketplace_myorderhistory_shipping" template="mpshippingmanager/myorderhistory.phtml" />
        </reference>

        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </marketplace_account_orderhistory>
    <marketplace_account_productlist>
        <reference name="content">
            <remove name="marketplace_myproductslist"></remove>
            <block type="marketplace/marketplace" name="marketplace_myproductslist_shipping" template="mpshippingmanager/myproductlist.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </marketplace_account_productlist>  
</layout>
```

Comment: did the block for both phtml is same too?

Comment: which means????

Comment: paste ur xml too for adding the phtml file

Comment: Check my updated question

Comment: try to load your order by order id `$order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load('order id');` and then check

Comment: check my updated question where i want to add this

Comment: what you want to achieve here?

Comment: Let us assume i have 2 page Myorderhistory & invoice. In invoice page seller can process order same way i need to process order in Myorderhistory itself

Comment: Like Generate in voice & shipment

Comment: this will not work like that because in inovice i think single invoice is displaying but orderhisotry there are multiple order displaying am i correct?

Comment: yes how to achive this?

Comment: add code inside the order displaying loop..

Comment: yes i add inside loop only but that div show empty

Comment: can you add the loop code too. it is better for understanding

Comment: check my updated question. i added(full myorderhistory.phtml) code under check_now class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this

```
$_order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));
```

with

```
$_order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($res['mageorderid']);
```

Comment: Now it's showing Shipping - Charges : but i have a button it's not showing on that

Comment: Button like Invoice & shipement it's not showing on that page

Comment: change this too `$orderItems=$this->getOrderItems();` to `$orderItems=$_order->getOrderItems();` and check the code accordingly

Comment: now also same i changed all place else part only work

Comment: yes check there is used $this change it according to that..

Comment: Sorry bro i didn't get this

Comment: $this is refer to current block if in your code use this change it according to block..

Comment: ok what i need to change

Comment: `$tracking=$this->getTrackingNumber($_order->getId());` add it in current block this method `getTrackingNumber` as far i notice  seen them

Comment: Ok i will check it

Comment: after change this i got Call to undefined function getTrackingNumber() error

Comment: bro copy from invoice block and add to current then it will work

Comment: i added in same way only after remove $this only i got this error

Comment: i told $this is refer to current you have to add method in block

Comment: where i need to add this

Comment: copy from `Block/Invoice.php` to `Block/Salesdetail.php`

Comment: Still now same only can i add that file in my question

Comment: i remembered that i will take you put five to six question to add this code. kindly read it change accordingly. you main problem is solved. now try to solve one by one..

Comment: Ok i will change it

Comment: No luck bro i changed still same only no changes

Comment: can you please tell me what i will change

Comment: you have to check what data this code are getting from block class just make the same code for both that is start working. and check the error log for errors

Comment: i ty this copy from Block/Invoice.php to Block/Salesdetail.php but it's not working

Comment: no it is not work like that.. can you tell waht are missing so i can focus on tat

Comment: actully that order status not showing

Comment: How to get that order process status in my orderhistory

Comment: try  `echo $custom_order_status = $_order->getStatus(); ` after order load

Comment: ya it showing order status but we need to chage order status here

Comment: you have have action them just put there they will start working

Comment: sorry i din't get i want to process their order like invoice shipment

Comment: you are doing on the button click add button for every order and they work like same

Comment: yes i want that only in myorder history page

Comment: it's directely go to else condition that's the problem

Comment: post a new condition with you order load  code and you condtion and kindly put the 
 
 echo $custom_order_status = $_order->getStatus();  output too

Comment: check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99298/order-process-in-seller